# Bootstrap view results from a query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, haml

I am working on a rail, bootstrap, and haml project right now.  I have a table below and I am trying to create a few ways that I can limit the number of results from the query.  I have it set up that I can already query a person's name, I am just trying to find a way that i can limit the amount of views say from 10 a page to 100 based on the query.  I would also like to add previous and next buttons along with the max results of the page.

Suggestions?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe you're looking for a way to paginate your results and vary the number of results returned by ActiveRecord. For that, you can simply install a pagination gem. I'd recommend something like [kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) or [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate).

Now to limit the amount of views per page, you can simply add something like this to your model (in kaminari):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  paginates_per 50
end
```

Or in your various controller actions, you can vary the number of results per page like so:

```
User.page(7).per(50)
```

which would return the seventh page of User, with 50 results per page.
It's a pretty well documented project with a lot of examples!

Comment: @Ancor beat me to the answer but here's a link to a [Railscast for using the kaminari gem for pagination](http://railscasts.com/episodes/254-pagination-with-kaminari). HTH